# Overscroll in MonoDevelop

Tags: ide, monodevelop, usability, overscroll

Is there a way to enable overscrolling in MonoDevelop?

With overscrolling I mean a feature to scroll the last line of the text up to the top of the editor instead only to the bottom.

If I'm working on the last few lines of a file I often fill in a couple of empty lines to get my focus in the middle of the window. I know this feature from Visual Studio and wonder if there is something similar in MonoDevelop.

Edit: I currently use MonoDevelop 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed few months ago: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17863 and is avaiable in Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop 5.0

Comment: Thank you! I'm very glad that they reimplemented that feature. So I've just to wait for MonoDevelop 5 packages for ubuntu.

Comment: I just discovered that the ppa https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/monodevelop provides MonoDevelop5 for Ubuntu... problem solved :-)